# Porting jupyter lab via ssh -L with interactive figures (TkAgg)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, portforwarding

I am trying to set up a jupyter lab on a linux machine and access it locally on my mac.

Following [this post](https://www.blopig.com/blog/2018/03/running-jupyter-notebook-on-a-remote-server-via-ssh/) I was able to do exactly that. The notebook generally works well, except it cannot plot figures using any sort of interactive backend. If I use %matplotlib widget all figures in the notebook as just a blank plot. With %matplotlib inline the figures plot, but no ability to zoom or anything.

If I try to run

```
from matplotlib import use 
use('TkAgg')
```

Which is required for one part of my notebook, I get:

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

I've ensured tkinter is installed, plotly is installed. I tried adding -X to the ssh command (the extent of my ssh knowledge).